# Issue With writing HTML inside PHP

Tags: php, html

For days, this codes worked fine in my server:

```
<?php

$myname="alisha";

if($myname==="alisha"){
?>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<p>I am really Alisha</p>

<?

}

?>
```

But since hours ago, it doesn't work. But if I change it as:

```
<?php

$myname="alisha";
if($myname==="alisha") echo '

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<p>I am really Alisha</p>
';

?>
```

It works fine. But I can't change all my php files into the last form because it's a lot. Please give me idea why it happens. Thank you.

Comment: Have you disabled PHP short tags?

Comment: What error do you get with the original code?

Comment: did you change the short tags value in your config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
<?php

$myname="alisha";

if($myname==="alisha"){
?>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<p>I am really Alisha</p>

<?

}

?>
```

Its using short tag

so if server is upgraded then probably u need to set the php.ini to enable short tags.

```
short_open_tag=On
```

That way you do  not need to change all the files.

Answer (score 0):

your second open tag is missing php

```
<?php

$myname="alisha";

if($myname==="alisha"){
?>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<p>I am really Alisha</p>

<?php

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say there was an update for PHP, the INI file does not accept short opening tags any more and your second php part is not interpreted as PHP. Just always use `<?php` instead of `<?`

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable to Short Open tag as Dikesh commented.

clean way :

```
<?php if($myname==="alisha"): ?>
 <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
 <p>I am really Alisha</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "php" to your second open tag, best practice is to always include the "php" it will eliminate this problem and any others that can be caused by this.

```
<?php

$myname="alisha";

if($myname==="alisha"){
?>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<p>I am really Alisha</p>

<?php

}

?>
```

Side Note - if you using this content/script on a lot of pages i recommend using a include statement, it will elimitante the need to change one thing on multiple pages. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Also a cleaner way of writing this would be:

```
<?php if($myname==="alisha"): ?>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><p>I am really Alisha</p>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

Keep things short and simple :)